# Moving a QGraphicsItem around a central point in PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qgraphicsitem

I'm using Python 2.7 and PyQt4. I am trying to have a half-circle object that is a QGraphicsItem. I want to be able to move it using the mouse, by clicking and dragging. I can create the object and move it around with the mouse by setting the flag ItemIsMovable. Now the half-circle moves around freely but I want it to move just around the fixed central point. It is difficult to describe, but it should be something similar to a dial. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qgraphicsitem.html#mouseMoveEvent) event to track item's movements within the scene and correct its position once it's moved off the restricted area. Pls, check if an example below would work for you:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class TestEclipseItem(QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)

        # set move restriction rect for the item
        self.move_restrict_rect = QtCore.QRectF(20, 20, 200, 200)
        # set item's rectangle
        self.setRect(QtCore.QRectF(50, 50, 50, 50))

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        # check of mouse moved within the restricted area for the item 
        if self.move_restrict_rect.contains(event.scenePos()):
            QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)

class MainForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__(parent)

        scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(-50, -50, 600, 600)

        ellipseItem = TestEclipseItem()
        scene.addItem(ellipseItem)

        view = QtGui.QGraphicsView()
        view.setScene(scene)
        view.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 400, 200))
        self.setCentralWidget(view)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Thanks. This works great and I will probably end up using this, but if there is another way to do it via another library or class, that would be great. What I would like to do should be similar to an analog clock with its hand dragable by the mouse. Right now I'm looking for something like an example of a clock, but your example also works great.

Comment: take a look at the analog clock example here: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/widgets-analogclock.html